# Problem with cors on not main/another api

Tags: axios, cors, frontend, backend, svelte

Let's say you need to install cors on the server and do the configuration, but here's the problem. I use Svelte for my application, but I use as the main api not my own, but the api that is located on this [link](https://gdchallengelist.com/api/v1/). But I can't configure the cors there, what should I do? Moreover, all attempts on the frontend to somehow change the cors, setting access-control-allow-origin and other headers, making the proxy server did not work. How to get out of this situation, I have a deadline soon.

Answer (score 0):

`CORS` needs to be configured on the server side, meaning the site `https://gdchallengelist.com/api/v1/` should allow `yourdomain.com` to access the endpoints. CORS is a browser policy enforced on the client side, so if you were to make a request to the same endpoint via `curl` or HTTP clients such as Postman or insomnia you will not see any CORS errors they are bypassed.

**Method 1:** Setup an express server that hits the endpoint and allows cors on your app. This requires a server to run beside your client side app.

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

**Method 2:** Setup cors-anywhere as per this [video](https://youtu.be/EHikjXtRp_k?t=1223) I have shared the timeline where cors is set up on rollup itself.

Comment: Okey, maybe I’m dumb, but why I must do own express server? I just can’t understand example, you mean, create own endpoints over api endpoints or what?

Comment: So you proxy the requests to your app.

Comment: I agree, CORS is not something you can get around in the browser. It is enforced by the browser itself to prevent people from 'stealing' access to APIs that they do not have permission to reuse.